# Controller action is not invoked in asp.net core

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I read the book 'Pro Entity Framework Core 2 for ASP.NET MVC'. I'm currently at the beginning of chapter 12 and have some problems. I have this controller:

```
namespace DataApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IDataRepository repository;

        public HomeController(IDataRepository repo)
        {
            repository = repo;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(repository.GetAllProducts());
        }

        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.CreateMode = true;
            return View("Editor", new Product());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Product product)
        {
            repository.CreateProduct(product);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        public IActionResult Edit(long id)
        {
            ViewBag.CreateMode = false;
            return View("Editor", repository.GetProduct(id));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit(Product product)
        {
            repository.UpdateProduct(product);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Delete(long id)
        {
            repository.DeleteProduct(id);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
}
```

The index view looks like this:

```html
@model IEnumerable<DataApp.Models.Product>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Products";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<table class="table table-sm table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Category</th><th>Price</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var p in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@p.Id</td>
                <td>@p.Name</td>
                <td>@p.Category</td>
                <td>$@p.Price.ToString("F2")</td>
                <td>
                    <form asp-action="Delete" method="post">
                        <a asp-action="Edit"
                           class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" asp-route-id="@p.Id">
                            Edit
                        </a>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@p.Id" />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                            Delete
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<a asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary">Create New Product</a>
```

If I run the application and click the Edit or Create button, I don't get the Editor view. If I navigate in the browser to /Home/Edit, then the view is shown. What can be the problem?

You can find the complete source code for this chapter here:

[Chapter 2](https://github.com/Apress/pro-ef-core-2-for-asp.net-core-mvc/tree/master/12%20-%20Performing%20Data%20Operations/DataApp/DataApp)

Please note, that I'm at the beginning of the chapter and the files in the source code may contain more, that I currently have, but according to the book, it should work on this stage too.

Comment: Can you tell me the error message or image after you clicked the Edit or Create button? I tested your code and the result is displayed normally.

Comment: My fault. It was an '@' missing in the viewimport file before the 'addTagHelper' command.